# Amazon auto-scaling through web console/panel

Tags: amazon-web-services, hosting, cloud, scalability

In Amazon AWS, is it currently possible to configure load balancing and autoscaling with the web console / panel?

The whole infrastructure seems to be configurable with a few clicks but I only found CLI tutorials to manage autoscaling. Is there no way to manage it with a graphical interface?

I want to propose Amazon solutions to my company, but it is hard to defend the replacement of one command line mess with another command line mess.

Thanks.

PS: Trying to avoid third-party solutions please.

Answer (score 3):

You can manage Elastic Load Balancers from the graphical console. Documentation is [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/GettingStarted.html).

There's still no graphical interface for auto scaling. The Amazon command line documentation is [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AutoScaling/latest/GettingStartedGuide/Welcome.html). You might also skim [this tutorial](http://www.cardinalpath.com/autoscaling-your-website-with-amazon-web-services-part-1/) on configuring auto scaling and load balancing.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can still manage auto-scaling from AWS web-console. I believe Amazon must be working on it, but I am for sure that it is available from web.

BTW, working with AWS Auto-Scaling shouldn't be a problem, I manage to setup my settings in just three commands - that's it go.

Take a look at this - http://www.codebelay.com/blog/2009/08/02/how-to-load-balance-and-auto-scale-with-amazons-ec2/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Amazon doesn't offer an online GUI yet. 3rd party tools do exist (though you mentioned you didn't want to use them): http://www.ezautoscaling.com, http://ylastic.com.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon recently added autoscaling configuration to the management console. You can read more about it here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/GettingStartedTutorial.html